# error Unknown property duplicationAA.contro in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

vf page

apex code

```
public class duplicationAA {
    List<aggregateResult> Duplica {get;set;}
    List<Contact> contro {get;set;}
    contact c {get;set;}
    public List<aggregateResult> getDuplicamethod()
    {
        contro=new List<Contact>();
        Duplica=new List<aggregateResult>();

        Duplica=[SELECT Department,Email,LastName,Name,Phone,Title,count(id) FROM Contact 
                 GROUP BY Department,Email,LastName,Name,Phone,Title HAVING count(id)>1];

        for(aggregateResult a:Duplica){
            Contact c=new Contact(Department=(String)a.get('Department'),
                                  Email=(String)a.get('Email'),
                                  LastName=(String)a.get('LastName'),
                                  Phone=(String)a.get('Phone'),
                                  Title=(String)a.get('Title'));
            contro.add(c);
        }
        return Duplica;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variables should be `public` else it will not be accessible in vf page

get set property variable should be `public`

```
public List<Contact> contro  {get;set;}
```